# Creating a WordPress Loop Within an Archive Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress archive page. I currently have a loop that is separating all of my image posts by month, but because of the way it is generating the month name within the loop, I am unable to control it the way I need to and am stumped on how to handle it.

I need to create a single div surrounding all the img's for each month. Ideally it would work like:

**MONTH NAME**

(new div)

- image
- image
- image

(/ new div)

**MONTH NAME**

(new div)

- image
- image
- image

(/ new div)

...etc

Any help would be so greatly appreciated

```
<?php       
$ref_month = '';
$monthly = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1));
if( $monthly->have_posts() ) :
while( $monthly->have_posts() ) : $monthly->the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
    $year_year = get_the_date('Y');
    $year_month = get_the_date('m'); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_month_link( $year_year, $year_month ); ?>">
        <?php
        if( get_the_date('mY') != $ref_month ) {
            if( $ref_month ) ?>

                <div class="month_name">
                    <?php echo get_the_date('F'); ?>
                </div>

            <?php
            $ref_month = get_the_date('mY');
        } ?>

        <?php 
        $year_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'year_image' ); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $year_image[0]; ?>" height="200px" width="200px" style="display:inline"/>
    </a>

<?php
endwhile; ?>

</ul>

<?php
endif; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference tutorial: http://callmenick.com/post/create-a-wordpress-custom-archive-page

```
  <?php

    global $post;

    $archive_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post', // get only posts
      'posts_per_page'=> -1 // this will display all posts on one page
    );

    $archive_query = new WP_Query( $archive_args );
    $year_year     = get_the_date('Y');
    $year_month    = get_the_date('m');

  ?>

  <div class="loop-archive">

    <?php $date_old = ''; ?>

    <?php while ( $archive_query->have_posts() ) : $archive_query->the_post(); ?>

      <?php $date_new = get_the_time("F Y"); ?>

      <?php if ( $date_old != $date_new ) : // run the check on $date_old and $date_new, and output accordingly ?>
        </div><!-- close the div -->
        <h4>
        <a href="<?php echo get_month_link( $year_year, $year_month ); ?>"> 
        <?php echo $date_new; ?>
        </a>
        </h4>
        <div style="border:1px dotted red;margin-bottom: 3%"><!-- open the div -->
      <?php endif; ?>

      <div style="display:inline">
      <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?></a>
      </div>

      <?php $date_old = $date_new; // update $date_old ?>

      <?php endwhile; // end the custom loop ?>

  </div> <!-- /loop-archive -->

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // always reset post data after a custom query ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@mikekavouras Helped me clean up the solution for this if anyone wants to see. I was able to generate the number of posts within each month so that I could create different patterns of grids with all the different background images based on how many posts there were

```
global $post;

$archive_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // get only posts
    'posts_per_page'=> -1 // this will display all posts on one page
);
$archive_query = new WP_Query( $archive_args );
$formatted_data = []; ?>

<?php while ( $archive_query->have_posts() ) : $archive_query->the_post(); 
    $date_new = get_the_time("M Y"); 
    $key = $date_new;

    if (! isset($formatted_data[$date_new])) {
        $formatted_data[$date_new] = [];
    }

    array_push($formatted_data[$date_new], $post); ?>
<?php endwhile; 

// loop through each month
$keys = array_keys($formatted_data);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++): ?>
    <?php 
    $month = $keys[$i]; 
    $posts = $formatted_data[$month]; 
    $num_posts = count($posts);
    $explosion = explode(" ", $month);
    $monthNum = array(
        "Jan" => 1,
        "Feb" => 2, 
        "Mar" => 3,
        "Apr" => 4,
        "May" => 5,
        "Jun" => 6,
        "Jul" => 7,
        "Aug" => 8,
        "Sep" => 9,
        "Oct" => 10,
        "Nov" => 11,
        "Dec" => 12
    );
    $month_abbr = $explosion[0];
    $year_month = $monthNum[$month_abbr];
    $year_year = $explosion[1]; ?>

    <div class="archive-month">
        <a href="<?php echo get_month_link( $year_year, $year_month ); ?>">

            <div class="<?php echo "archivebox archivebox--" . $num_posts; ?>">

                <div class="archive-name">
                    <h2><?php echo $month; ?></h2>
                </div>

                <?php for ($j = 0; $j < count($posts); $j++): ?> 
                    <?php 
                    $p = $posts[$j];
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID);
                    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail');

                    <!-- you have the post do whatever you want -->
                    <div class="archive-background" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumb_url[0]; ?>');"></div>


                <?php endfor; ?>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php 
endfor; ?>
```